# SpecFlow Inserting New feature not working

Tags: automated-tests, specflow

I just have downloaded SpecFlow test project from bitbucket repository. Its working fine. Now I want to Add more features to it. It doesn't Automatically create feature cs file. and also test not appearing in test Explorer.

Comment: Share with us additional info about SpecFlow version, VS version...

Answer (score 0):

**To Add a new Feature file**

1. Right Click on your folder that you want to contain your feature files in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click add => New Item
3. In the Search box on the top right Type "Feature", an option for "Specflow Feature File" should show up. Rename the file how you like and click add.

To get the Feature files To display in the Test explorer try cleaning the solution and rebuilding. If this doesn't work we need
    more info.